# Javascript to remove bb_quotes ([quote..] [/quote]) from text

Tags: javascript, regex

The goal is to use Javascript (vanilla) to remove all text (inclusive) that is between: [quote]*[/quote] and [quote=something]*[/quote] (case insensitive). It would be best to also remove double spaces, if they exist after removing the quotes. I tried this Javascript as below, ie:

```
t.replace(/\[quote.*\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/gi,'')
```

, but I don't get the correct results. What is the correct way?

```js
var t='Starting [QUOTE]this should be ignored hello[/quote] it. This is not quote and [quote=frank]HELLO quotes[/quote] Marky Mark 84WD. Last [quote=irene]try.[/quote]';

console.log(t.replace(/\[quote.*\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/gi,''));

//Current result: Starting.
//Expected result: Starting it. This is not quote and Marky Mark 84WD. Last

var t='[Quote]this should be ignored hello[/quote]. This is not quote and [quote=frank]HELLO quote[/quote] Marky Mark 84WD.';

console.log(t.replace(/\[quote.*\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/gi,''));

//Current result: Marky Mark 84WD.
//Expected result: . This is not quote and Marky Mark 84WD.
```

Comment: His code has two arguments. See the empty string after the first one.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the top example (in the code there were 2 arguments correctly).

Comment: @Pytth the question was edited.

Comment: @Pointy Yea, I saw that the first line was incorrect, but later in the code example he was showing the full usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/\[(quote)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/\1\]/gi` to achieve the filtering:

```js
var t='Starting [QUOTE]this should be ignored hello[/quote] it. This is not quote and [quote=frank]HELLO quotes[/quote] Marky Mark 84WD. Last [quote=irene]try.[/quote]';

console.log(t.replace(/\[(quote)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/\1\]/gi,''));

var t='[Quote]this should be ignored hello[/quote]. This is not quote and [quote=frank]HELLO quote[/quote] Marky Mark 84WD.';

console.log(t.replace(/\[(quote)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/\1\]/gi,''));
```

Comment: Hm, but it seems that this code doesn't ignore words between [quote*][/quote] if they are in new line (I mean in a textarea), like:

[quote]
word1\n
word2 (in new line)\n
word3 (in new line)\n
[/quote]

Is it possible to include such quotes to filter them too?

Comment: For example, this counts in JS as 2 words: 
something
[quote]dssdsf sd ds sd ds fsdf ds[/quote]

BUT this counts as 8 words (one word within [quote] is in a new line (represented by \n):

something
[quote]dssdsf\n

sd ds sd ds fsdf ds[/quote]

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by adding this new replacement: t.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'')